Is it shirk to watch animes that contain shirk? And if it does, can we just skip those parts that contain shirk and watch it. And like the good parts?
I have been obsessed with some character in the anime 'My hero academia' but recently I have figured out that one of the character's 'hero' name has god In it. So , will the whole anime be shirk to watch for that one character? I figured that out yesterday and I was highly disgusted about the fact they named a character's 'hero name' such thing. Now I even wonder will it be Haram to watch that character or like that character? Cuz he actually has a name katsuki Bakugo apart from his hero name great dynamic explosion god or whatever. Nowzubillah.

Yes, watching anime that contain shirk is considered shirk. Shirk is the gravest sin in Islam and involves associating partners with Allah or giving worship to anything or anyone other than Allah. If an anime contains elements of shirk, such as promoting polytheism or idolatry, watching it is considered a form of shirk.
It is important to be mindful of the content we consume and ensure it aligns with Islamic values. If you enjoy anime, there are many halal alternatives available that do not contain shirk.
